# Convert MySQL "where" to Sequelizejs "where"

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js

I was trying to write "WHERE (CASE ... THEN ... ELSE ... END) > 0" to sequelize v3.33 but couldn't find the solution yet.

Had tried sequelize.literal('...') but didn't work.
Using "HAVING" is one of the solutions but it's no good for performance-wise for large data extraction and it's twice as slow.

This is just an example of MySQL code but pretty much close to what I want to achieve.

```
SELECT
(CASE `a`.`fee` IS NULL 
  THEN `a.b`.`fee` 
  ELSE `a`.`fee`
END) AS `_fee`
FROM `a`
WHERE
(CASE `a`.`fee` IS NULL 
  THEN `a.b`.`fee` 
  ELSE `a`.`fee`
END) > 0 AND 
(created_at > currentDate 
  AND 
created_at < futureDate)
```

I want to convert this to sequelize. Below is as far as I can go, I don't know how to add that case closure.

```
models.a.findAll({
  ...
  where: {
    created_at: { $gt: startDate, $lt: endDate }
  }
})
```

*** Don't mind about created_at, it's just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sequelize.where` and `sequelize.literal` for that :

```
where:{
    $and : [
        { created_at: { $gt: startDate, $lt: endDate } },
        sequelize.where(sequelize.literal('(CASE `a`.`fee` IS NULL THEN `a.b`.`fee` ELSE `a`.`fee` END)') , { $gt : 0 } )
    ]
}
```

> Note : this might not work as alias `a`. of the table might be diff, you can debug and change as per your query

Comment: Although my code doesn't work as I expected because my query is still a little bit off but this code work! It generates SQL exactly how I wanted it. Just wondering, in generated SQL there are `((` `))` double curly braces around CASE like `((CASE...END) > 0)` makes any difference I don't know because my query doesn't work yet. Thanks! Answer accepted!